# Android Book Search App Search Results Layout Out Of Screen Occasionally

Tags: java, android

I was tasked to create a simple book searching app for Android as an internship project. I'm almost done with this, but I'm very bad at doing layouts. The published date and description will ALWAYS fly to the left and out of the screen if the ISBN number is 10 digits long, but it's perfectly fine when its just 13 digits long. Just for reference, I'm using the google books API. This would be much clearer if I could post pictures, but my rep is too low for that.

Here's my code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>

<ImageView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img_cover"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_books_large"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_cover"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_cover" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Author"
    android:id="@+id/tvAuthor"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_cover"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_cover" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_cover"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:text="ISBN"
         android:id="@+id/tvISBN"
         android:layout_below="@+id/img_cover"
         />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:text="Publish Date"
         android:id="@+id/tvPublishYear"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvISBN"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="-220dp"
         />

<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPublishYear"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-270dp"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:text="Description"

     />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nvm fixed it.
Just had to add
android:orientation="vertical"

to LinearLayout